# Cannot retrieve programmatically a certificate installed through mmc for a service account

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, windows-server-2008, x509certificate2

I'm trying to turn an application into a service (.NET). This service has to log in remote server through a Web Service (FileNet P8 .NET credential system).

However, the URL is **HTTPS** so it requires a certificate.

I followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc780545(v=ws.10)) to install a certificate for a service account with MMC. The certificate (self-signed) is installed in *Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store*. (Disclaimer: I don't really understand yet how MMC works, especially when changes made with are effective).

The certificate is present in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\ Services\<ServiceName>\SystemCertificates\Root\Certificates\<digitalFootprint>`.

However, this piece of code doesn't retrieve the certificate :

```
' Environment.UserName = SERVICE LOCAL (french)
LOGGER.info("Certifs for " & Environment.UserName)
Dim store As X509Certificates.X509Store =
    New X509Certificates.X509Store(X509Certificates.StoreName.Root,
                                   X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
store.Open(X509Certificates.OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
For Each certificate As X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 In store.Certificates
    LOGGER.info(certificate.Issuer & ": " & 
                If(certificate.Verify, "Valid", "Invalid"))
Next 
LOGGER.info("End Certifs")
```

Of course, the test code below fails:

```
Dim wq As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("https://<URL>")
Dim reader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(wq.GetResponse.GetResponseStream)
LOG.info(reader.ReadToEnd)
```

But if I run the service with a user account which does have the certificate, it runs. What did I do wrong?

Additional question: is there a way to run Internet Explorer with a service account to perform the certificate installation with it? (As a workaround)

Comment: The only way to do this is to run in service's impersonated context and query "CurrentUser\My" store.

Comment: @Crypt32, you mean it's  pointless to add a certificate to a service account? If so, why it's possible through MMC?

Comment: This is a limitation of .NET Framework API. CryptoAPI provides such functionality, it is not implemented in .NET.

Comment: @Crypt32 Oh. Thank you for the hint. Do you have a source about this limitation?

Comment: here is the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore

Comment: @Crypt32, thanks for the link. I'm sorry to take you more time if I missed something, this page is about the use of `CertOpenStore()` from the Win32 API, not the .NET one. It may contain details about .NET api limitations, but I didn't find it. If this page is sufficient by itself, that's okay I will try to figure out by myself how it links to the .NET limitations.

Comment: .NET uses `CertOpenStore` function behind `X509Store` class. `CertOpenStore` supports service account stores, .NET implementation doesn't, because it is not implemented.

Comment: @Crypt32, I think I found the "proof" that .NET doesn't implement this feature. In [x509utils.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509utils.cs,69c8c351916e34c2), `X509Utils.MapX509StoreFlags()` (called by `X509Certificates.X509Store.Open()`) method only manages `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER` locations flags. Is this correct?

Comment: @Crypt32, if it's correct, if you wish to write an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Otherwise, I'll write it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET doesn't support certificate lookup in service account stores. The underlying API [CertOpenStore function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore) has support for service account stores via `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_SERVICE` and `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_SERVICES` values. .NET has support only for `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER` values in [StoreLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storelocation?view=netcore-3.1) enumeration.

MMC uses native APIs, thus you can access services certificate stores from MMC. This is sort of known limitation in .NET. The only way to overcome it is to use `CertOpenStore` function directly (via p/invoke).

Comment: Is my comment about `X509Utils.MapX509StoreFlags()` relevant? If so, do you mind if I complete your answer with?

Comment: It is sort of relevant for deep investigation. But generally, the answer is found in `StoreLocation` enumeration. I've added this reference in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once I also faced similar kind of behaviour..lets see if below code can help you, remember our certificate was personal certificate:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "test.supportxxxx@test.com", true);
if (certificates.Count > 0)
 {
     // certificate found            
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried, it works with a regular account (ie the certificat is found and the HTTPS connexion success, but not if the service ran with a service account).